# How can I reset/clear a interface attribute in composition api + typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have 2 fields in my component, of which I use an interface, and I have a button to "clear" these fields, but I cant do that because vue is breaking reactivity :(

```
interface Campaign {
 name: string,
 points: string,
}
```

So, in my composition api, I make the reactive reference like this.

```
    setup() {
      let campaign = reactive<Campaign>({
        name: 'John Doe',
        points: '300',
      });

//this works in JS vanilla
      const clearFields = () => {
        campaign = {
          name: null,
          points: null
        };
      };

      return { campaign, clearFields }
    }
```

Comment: `//this works in JS...` - TypeScript shouldn't change the behavior of your app; do you mean it's throwing a compiler error? Are you calling `clearFields` and getting a different result than expected? It's a bit unclear what the exact problem is.

Comment: @ConnorLow This function does not clear the attributes

Answer (score 2):

When you set `campaign` in `clearFields`, you are pointing to a new object, **not** the result of `reactive<Campaign>()` above. Example:

```js
const foo = reactive<Foo>({ bar: 'hello' });

let foobar = foo; 
// foobar -> foo
// foo    -> `result of reactive<Foo>()`
foobar = { bar: 'there' }; 
// foobar -> `{ bar: 'there' }`
// foo    -> `result of reactive<Foo>()`
```

You probably want to do this:

```js
const clearFields = () => {
  campaign.name = null;
  campaign.points = null;
};
```

Here you are just reassigning the properties of `campaign` rather than the object itself.

Comment: Wow didn't know that. Worked perfectly. Thank you man!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is true in (as far as I know) every language. Think of a variable as a pointer to a bit of memory: when you reassign the variable, you point to a new bit of memory (which may or may not invalidate/remove the old bit).